# How to setup NFS on 13.04 and 12.10

Tags: mount, nfs

I used my 12.10 as my NFS server. 
And the 13.04 as the client.
After installing NFS to both of my laptops
I added this in /etc/exports

1. /export       client.ip.add.ress/24(rw,fsid=0,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)
2. /export/users client.ip.add.ress/24(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async)

then I tried to run on my 13.04 this

$ sudo mount servername:/export/users /mnt

then I got the error
mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server servername: System error

I tried to follow the instructions in [this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo#Portmap_Lockdown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't make clear in your question as to how you have set up name resolution in your network for your server.
Do you have a DNS server configured with the name of the server in it or have you added the server-name to the hosts file on your client.

A couple of ways you could progress here:

Check in file /etc/hosts for an entry  of the form:
server_ipaddress   servername

or

Try

```
$ sudo mount server_ip_address:/export/users /mnt
```

or

Try:

```
$ sudo mount servername.local:/export/users /mnt
```

I think 13.04 deploys avahi by default which provides a service called multicast dns using this allows all hosts to be identifed as hostname.local

HTH

Rob

Comment: Thanks! It works! Haha. I don't have the DNS server configured so I just replaced the servername by its ip address. Thanks again!